# Coredata: opening an xcdatamodeld file

Tags: core-data

I have a single xcdatamodeld file and would merely like to open this particular file with xcode. However, when I double click the file, it doesn't really show me anything or allow editing. The only way to do this is to run MyApp.xcodeproj and only then can I modify this file. Isn't there any way to edit the coredata file using only the xcdatamodel file? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The xcdatamodeld file is not actually a file - it's a directory containing other model files.

Right click the file, choose `Show Package Contents` and you will get access to the files inside the directory. You can then double-click those files. When I do so I get just the Xcode model editor without the full Xcode project window.